# Non standard file extensions in SaveFileDialog CLI / CLR / C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I'm using CLI/CLR and unmanaged code, but this question pertains to the CLI/CLR part and I have observed the same behavior with c# code.

I'm trying to save a file with a legacy filename that does not conform to the standard file extension rules.
The file extension is "-C2.txt", unfortunately when I use the SaveFileDialog::Filter method the filename does not include the "-C2" part. Is there a work around in SaveFileDialog that will let me do this?

```
SaveFileDialog^ cDlg = gcnew SaveFileDialog;
cDlg->Filter = "csv file (*.csv)|*.csv|-C2.txt file (*-C2.txt)|*-C2.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
```

Example:

1. In the SaveFileDialog box I select an existing file "File01.csv" and that is then placed in the existing "File name:" text box in the SaveFileDialog box.
2. The listView box displays only those files that fit the filter, e.g. only displays *-C2.txt files and not *.txt files.
3. However, I change the "Save as type:" comboBox to "-C2.txt" and the new filename is "file01.txt" and not "file01-C2.txt".

Comment: `-c2.txt` is not an extension, the `.txt` part is... a file extension is defined to be the last part of the file name after and including the last `.` in the name.

Comment: Right.  Just use .c2txt as an extension.  Three letter extensions avoid obscure problems with legacy short name support so don't hesitate to pick .c2t instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not way to get the dialog to do this for you. As Jeff Mercado states correctly "`-ct.txt` is not an extension, the `.txt` part is...".

The best solution I can offer you is to change the selected file path yourself, like so

```
string strFullPath = FileBrowser.Filename; // Has your "SomeFile.txt
string[] strTmpArr = strFullPath.Split('.');
strFullPath = String.Format("{0}-C2.txt", strTmpArr[0]);
```

Note this assumes that you do not have '.' anywhere else in the file path. You cannot use `Path.ChangeExtension()` as you `-C2.txt` will be made `.-C2.txt`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along the same lines as all of these & it looks like I'll have to give the users some more details on saving this particular type of file. The problem is the "-C2.txt" is a specific psuedo-extension that another legacy code (not mine) uses and that legacy code is extremely not user friendly. Bummer for them, lol.